# WKWebView not loading webpage - renders blank screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

This code is supposed to load the Apple homepage, but instead shows a blank screen.
This happens with both HTTP and HTTPS URLs.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate{

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

I have tried changing 'App Transport Security Settings' to allow arbitrary load. Didn't change anything.

**Screenshots:**

View hierarchy:

[image: Captured view hierarchy Screenshot]

Safari debug console for the simulator:

[image: Safari debug console Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine. I tried it in demo. I think it might be other issue.

Comment: I haven't used any storyboard files in my app. Its all code.

Comment: When is `loadView` called? Is it before or after `viewDidLoad`? I don't see it called anywhere, and that's where you actually create your web view

Comment: Yes the code is from Apple website, but don't know why i cannot get it to work. Its the first time I am using WKWebView.

Comment: Yes. as you did it works fine. try only this code in one demo.

Comment: loadView is called before viewDidLoad

Comment: Just because the code for `loadView` is written before `viewDidLoad`, doesn't make it automatically get _called_ before.

Comment: @user770   This code is from the Apple's official developer guide for WkWebView

Comment: And they say that loadView is called first?

Comment: @user770 yes looks like that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Comment: I don't know if this is the only way, but I added a webkit view in storyboard, make a outlet for it `@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!` , removed your `webView` var and replaced it with this outlet (line 7 I think), and it works.

Comment: @user770 My app doesn't use any storyboard or nib files at all. Its all in code. What should i do?

Comment: How does Xcode know which view to load first? The blank screen isn't because the page is not loading, it's because the **view** isn't. Try getting the screen to say "hello" using just code, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @user770 View is definitely loading, see the screenshot for captured view hierarchy. I put the background colour as red. I did also put breakpoint on both methods and they are executing for sure.

Comment: Did you manage to get "hello" on the screen by adding code to the same file we're working with?

Comment: I have the same issues, WKWebView works on device, but not Simulator. However, UIWebView works in the Simulator. I have BitDefender installed on my Mac, could that be what is causing WKWebView to not work in the Sim?

Comment: It could be. Open any iPhone simulator and launch safari app on the simulator, if you are not able to load any websites on the simulator’s safari, there is a good chance that the culprit might be Bitdefender or some similar software installed on the computer blocking the network

Comment: Here is the answer to a question with a similar problem!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285901/cant-load-my-web-view-with-an-http-url

Comment: In my case, it was blank because the site I'm loading needed camera permission. I added camera permission to my project and that fixed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was being caused by AVG AntiVirus's webshield. For some reason AVG webshield treats all network communication from the simulator as fraudulent. 
The following screenshot shows the safari app running on simulator. It says that www.apple.com is not safe or any other website.

[image: Safari screenshot]

The following screenshot is from system.log showing errors with webkit.

[image: System log]

You can replicate this problem by installing AVG antivirus and turning on the webshield. WKWebview in your App(On the simulator) wouldn't load anything.

I don't understand why it wasn't working on an actual device tho. It could have been another problem with the device. I also deleted the derived data folder, the actual app and had restarted the device.

Thank you everybody for the answers and help.

Comment: nailed it! its antivirus damn!

Comment: Just a quick note. I ran into this problem and I got the same as in his screenshot but it was because I was on our company's VPN. If I got off of VPN then it showed the web page.

Answer (score 15):

## Building an App for the Mac?

If you are building an app for the Mac, make sure to turn `App Sandbox` <kbd>ON</kbd> in your target and tick `Networks` Outgoing Connections.

[image]

---

Update: If you prefer the long way, add the following to <kbd>YourAppName.entitlements</kbd>

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Man, you rock, waiting 2 days and no solution is complete without your code snippet.Thanks dude.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wasted half an hour on this

Comment: The crazy thing is that even `webView.loadHTMLString` fails when outgoing connections are not allowed ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way with auto layout and constant 10 for all device:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

let webView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupWebView()
}

fileprivate func setupWebView() {
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com") else { return }
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}}
```

in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code works just fine for me in Xcode 9.3:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        self.view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    }

}
```

Here's the result:

[image: WKWebView in iOS Simulator.]

Comment: Its weird but it is still blank white screen for me.

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar Have you tried using other URLs?

Comment: Yes. I have tried a few different websites, using http, https, removing www

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar Try using the `isLoading` property of the `WKWebView` to debug.

Comment: printed out,  isLoading == true

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar Try it on a different simulator. This is extremely unusual.

Comment: iPhone 8 plus....its same problem. I tried with an actual device too, iPhone 6, same problem.

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar I think this might be a network issue. Because your code clearly works.

Comment: Dunno mate, everything else on the app related to network is working fine. Firebase requests, google map is all working fine. I just need WkWebview to load privacy policy and terms and conditions. I am stuck on this from a day now.

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar Yeah, I hate it when that happens. In terms of code solutions, I'm all out, but I'm invested in this problem. So, please add your answer if you do figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: It was AVG antivirus's Webshield causing the problem.

Comment: Ha! I figured it might be some network issue! Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Yeah mate you were correct regarding the network issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

var wkWebview: WKWebView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

    var Ycord : CGFloat = 0.0 // for top space 
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 812 { //Check for iPhone-x
        Ycord = 44.0
    }
    else {
        Ycord = 20.0
    }

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: Ycord, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-Ycord)

    self.wkWebview = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    self.wkWebview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.wkWebview.uiDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.wkWebview)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.wkWebview.load(URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    }        
 }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Please try now i changed some code. hope it will works

Comment: Still same thing mate.

Comment: i have tested above code and it working for me. attached screenshot. please try above code

Comment: With this code I am getting a black strip below navigation bar and a blank white screen below. I will add a screenshot to my question